# extjs4 why does not the api property work in Store

Tags: extjs4.1

I'm trying to take a test api property of ajax proxy in store, but seems it does not work.
I have no idea why it does not work. I've just followed reference book.
Would someone please give me an advice ? I've attached source code.

Below is source code for model.

```
Ext.define('directModel', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
fields : [
    {name : 'id',               type : 'int'},
    {name : 'firstName',        type : 'string'},
    {name : 'lastName',         type : 'string'},
    {name : 'company',          type : 'string'},
    {name : 'email',                type : 'string'},
    {name : 'dob',                  type : 'date'},
    {name : 'age',                  type : 'int'},
    {name : 'coworker',         type : 'string'}
    ]
});
```

Below is source code for store.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId : 'directStore',
    model : 'directModel',
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',          
        api : {
            read : '/common/command.jsp?action=read',
            create : '/common/command.jsp?action=add',
            update : '/common/command.jsp?action=update',                   
            destory : '/common/command.jsp?action=remove'
        },
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            root : 'root'
        },
        writer : {
            type : 'json',
            root : 'data'
        }
    }
});

var s = Ext.data.StoreManager.get('directStore');   
s.load({
    callback : function(){

        var r = Ext.ModelManager.create({
            id : '346012',
            firstName : '',
            lastName : '',
            company : '',
            email : '',
            dob : '',
            age : 3,
            coworker : 'N/A'
        }, 'directModel');

        s.add(r);
        s.sync();

    }
});
```

I just loaded store to bring the data from server side and I found out it's okay.
Also I tried to add new reocrd and invoke "sync" function.
As I know, request url should be create property of api. However nothing happened.

pls give me an advice.

Comment: Check your reader and writer root property:
- try without specifying the root property
- or make sure that "root" or "data" really are the correct values according to your backend.
If neither helps, post you server response.

Comment: What exactly doesnt work? What errors, unexpected behaviours?

Comment: Run it again and monitor with ie firebug what's being transmitted over the network. Add the "post requests" to your question.

Comment: 'Nothing happened' is not what a developer should say. What you expected did not happen. What does firebug or chrome developer tools say ? Put a `console.log()` before s.add and look if the callback gets executed. ExtJs really debugs easily with CDT and Firebug.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I found out that the spelling is wrong for destroy and I've removed "id" property from the model, now it's okay.